# how to make button outside the jpanel (top left position)

Tags: java, eclipse

this is my code please help to make the button move outside the jpanel

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.ApplicationException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

public class Voucher extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    JFrame myframes = new JFrame();

    public int xx = 0 ;
    
    JPanel centerpanel, northpanel,headpanel,voucher, back_img;
    JLabel fill1,fill2,fill3,label_title;
    JButton btn_back, btn_back2, backk;

    
    public void content () {
        
        
        back_img = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.paintComponent(g);
                try {
                    g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("Assets/voucherpage.png")), 0, 0, 1200, 700, null);
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
        };

    
        JButton picbutton1 = new JButton();
        picbutton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 10.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        JButton picbutton2 = new JButton();
        picbutton2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 20.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        JButton picbutton3 = new JButton();
        picbutton3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 30.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        JButton picbutton4 = new JButton();
        picbutton4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 40.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        JButton picbutton5 = new JButton();
        picbutton5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 10.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        JButton picbutton6 = new JButton();
        picbutton6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 20.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        JButton picbutton7 = new JButton();
        picbutton7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 30.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        JButton picbutton8 = new JButton();
        picbutton8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 40.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 190, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        
        headpanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout());
        northpanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        centerpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,4,60,60));
        centerpanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        myframes.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        back_img.add(centerpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        back_img.add(headpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        
        
        picbutton1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton2.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton3.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton4.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton5.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton6.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton7.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        picbutton8.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        
        northpanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));

        
        
        btn_back2 = initJButton("Back");
        northpanel.add(btn_back2);
        btn_back2.setLocation(0,0);
        
        label_title = initJLabel("Vouchers",50);
        northpanel.add(label_title);

        back_img.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        picbutton1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton7.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        picbutton8.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));

        centerpanel.add(picbutton1);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton2);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton3);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton4);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton5);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton6);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton7);
        centerpanel.add(picbutton8);
        
        
        picbutton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            picbutton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 10.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
            xx=0;
            validate();
            repaint();

            
            
            
        }
    });
        
        picbutton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            xx=1;
            picbutton2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 20.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
            validate();
            repaint();
            
            
        }
    });
        
        picbutton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xx=1;
                picbutton3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 30.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
                
                
                
            }
        });
            
        
        picbutton4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xx=1;
                picbutton4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/ongkir 40.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
                validate();
                repaint();
                
                
            }
        });
        
        picbutton5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                picbutton5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 10.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
                xx=0;
                validate();
                repaint();

                
                
                
            }
        });
        
        picbutton6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                picbutton6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 20.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
                xx=0;
                validate();
                repaint();

                
                
                
            }
        });
        
        picbutton7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                picbutton7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 30.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
                xx=0;
                validate();
                repaint();

                
                
                
            }
        });
        
        picbutton8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                picbutton8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/cashback 40.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(140, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
                xx=0;
                validate();
                repaint();

                
                
                
            }
        });
            
        
        
        back_img.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(70, 100, 30, 100));
        centerpanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));


        
        headpanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        northpanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        centerpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 100, 1, 100));
        centerpanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,44));
        
        add (back_img);
    }
    

    
    public Voucher() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        content ();
    
        
        this.setTitle("JP.ID");
        this.setSize(1200, 700);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        if(e.getSource() == btn_back2) {
            new Main(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
        
    }
    
    private JLabel initJLabel(String str, Integer size) {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(str);
        lbl.setForeground(Color.white);
        lbl.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD, size));
        return lbl;
    }
    
    private JButton initJButton(String str) {
        JButton but = new JButton(str);
        but.setBackground(Color.pink);
        but.setForeground(Color.red);
        but.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        but.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65,30));
        but.addActionListener(this);
        return but;
    }
    
}
```

PLease help me I wanna make the button to move outside the northpanel in top left position
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMVoT.png)

IGNORE THIS:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you're going to want to do, is break the UI down into "manageable" groups of functionality.

This will help you focus on what each individual section of your UI needs and how best you can achieve it.  It will also make it easier to manage complex layout relationships while isolating functionality and responsibility.

You should consider areas of re-use, instead of generating duplicate code, create re-usable components.

I spent a lot of time with your code previously and, well, simply couldn't make heads or tails of it, so I re-built it so as to replicate the desired layout as best as possible.

The following example focuses on grouping functionality together so as it simpler to layout and manage.  What I've not done is implemented any kind of delegation or observer workflow, which would be need to handle user interaction, but that wouldn't be overly difficult to implement.

[image: Example layout]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(new VoucherSelectionPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class VoucherSelectionPanel extends JPanel {

        public VoucherSelectionPanel() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBackground(Color.RED);

            JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(16, 16, 16, 16);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(backButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(24, 40, 40, 40);

            add(new BasePane(), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class BasePane extends JPanel {

        public BasePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
            TransparentPane contentPane = new TransparentPane(new BorderLayout());
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 80, 20, 80));
            contentPane.setAlpha(0.5f);

            JPanel vouchersPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4));
            vouchersPane.setOpaque(false);

            Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.PINK, Color.YELLOW, Color.DARK_GRAY};
            for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
                VoucherPanel pane = new VoucherPanel();
                pane.setBackground(colors[index]);
                vouchersPane.add(pane);
            }

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Vouchers");
            title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 0, 20));

            contentPane.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            contentPane.add(vouchersPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            add(contentPane);
        }

    }

    public class VoucherPanel extends JPanel {

        private JPanel voucherPane = new JPanel();

        public VoucherPanel() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            setOpaque(false);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            voucherPane.setBackground(getBackground());

            add(voucherPane);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBackground(Color bg) {
            super.setBackground(bg);
            if (voucherPane != null) {
                voucherPane.setBackground(bg);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(160, 260);
        }

    }

    public class TransparentPane extends JPanel {

        private float alpha = 1.0f;

        public TransparentPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public TransparentPane(LayoutManager layout) {
            super(layout);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
            this.alpha = Math.min(1.0f, Math.max(0f, alpha));
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(getAlpha()));
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fill(new Rectangle(getSize()));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```